# How to make a efficient comparator for javascript sort function for sorting an array of strings?

Tags: javascript, string, sorting, comparator

I have an array of strings which looks like :

```
array = ['third', 'first', 'fourth', 'second', 'custom2', 'custom1']
```

and I would like to sort this array, so it will looks like :

```
array = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'custom2', 'custom1']
```

Specific strings like *'first', 'second', ...* should be sorted in given order (first before second before third ...) and any other strings should be attached at the end in arbitrary order. An array containing only sub-set of those strings should be sorted in right order anyway :

```
['fourth', 'something', 'second'] => ['second', 'fourth', 'something']
```

I wonder if I there is an possibility to write a comparator function fot the javascript sort() function which would solve this problem effectively.

Comment: Can you post your code so far with a live demo and explain what didn't work?

Comment: Hmmm ... I do not really have a working code yet, I have this array of strings which are used as keys and i would like to sort them. So I searched for a possibility to do that, and found the comparator-function argument for the javascript sort() function. And I stuck by that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this?

```
array = ['third', 'first', 'fourth', 'second', 'custom2', 'custom1']
special = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']

array.sort(function(a, b) {
    var ia = special.indexOf(a)
    var ib = special.indexOf(b)

    if(ia >= 0 && ib >= 0) return ia - ib;

    if(ia >= 0) return -1;
    if(ib >= 0) return +1;

    return a > b ? 1 : a == b ? 0 : -1;
})

console.log(array)
[
 "first",
 "second",
 "third",
 "fourth",
 "custom1",
 "custom2"
]
```

or, better, using [schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

```
a = array.map(function(x) {
    var n = special.indexOf(x);
    return [n < 0 ? array.length : n, x]
}).sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a[0] - b[0]) || (a[1] > b[1] ? 1 : a[1] == b[1] ? 0 : -1);
}).map(function(x) {
    return x[1]
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this special array is a great idea, very nice code, thanks!

Comment: If i could i would give another **+1** for the _schwartzian transform_, just because you brought it back to my mind and i could perfectly use it later the day :D

Comment: Is it possible to alter your example for the case, that the array contains some ID's and should be sorted by associated values ? Like array = ['ID3', 'ID1', 'ID4', 'ID2', 'IDxz', 'IDxy']
pairs = {'ID3':'third', 'ID1':'first', 'ID4':'fourth', 'ID2':'second', 'IDxz':'custom2', 'IDxy':'custom1'} ?
I was able to alter your comparator function by replacing a/b with pairs[a]/pairs[b] but this does not work for the schwartzian transform.

Comment: @karlitos: just replace `n = special.indexOf(x)` with `n = pairs[x] || array.length`.